# After some Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS soft update 5 GHz wifi stopped working

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless

I recently noticed degradation of my wifi network, after checked I noticed that laptop uses only 2.4 GHz band instead 5 GHz. Some time ago I used 5 GHz wifi band without problem. Problem seems to be here:

```
HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ iw phy 
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 20
    max scan IEs length: 422 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 20
    max # match sets: 11
    max # scan plans: 2
    max scan plan interval: 65535
    max scan plan iterations: 254
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Device supports T-DLS.
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x11ef
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
        HT Max RX data rate: 300 Mbps
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x11ef
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
        HT Max RX data rate: 300 Mbps
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        VHT Capabilities (0x038071b0):
            Max MPDU length: 3895
            Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
            RX LDPC
            short GI (80 MHz)
            TX STBC
            SU Beamformee
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (disabled)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (disabled)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (disabled)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (disabled)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (disabled)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (disabled)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (disabled)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (disabled)
            * 5340 MHz [68] (disabled)
            * 5360 MHz [72] (disabled)
            * 5380 MHz [76] (disabled)
            * 5400 MHz [80] (disabled)
            * 5420 MHz [84] (disabled)
            * 5440 MHz [88] (disabled)
            * 5460 MHz [92] (disabled)
            * 5480 MHz [96] (disabled)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (disabled)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (disabled)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (disabled)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (disabled)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (disabled)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (disabled)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (disabled)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (disabled)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (disabled)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (disabled)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (disabled)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (disabled)
            * 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
            * 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
            * 5885 MHz [177] (disabled)
            * 5905 MHz [181] (disabled)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_config
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * frame
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * tdls_mgmt
         * tdls_oper
         * start_sched_scan
         * probe_client
         * set_noack_map
         * register_beacons
         * start_p2p_device
         * set_mcast_rate
         * connect
         * disconnect
         * channel_switch
         * set_qos_map
         * add_tx_ts
         * set_multicast_to_unicast
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    WoWLAN support:
         * wake up on disconnect
         * wake up on magic packet
         * wake up on pattern match, up to 20 patterns of 16-128 bytes,
           maximum packet offset 0 bytes
         * can do GTK rekeying
         * wake up on GTK rekey failure
         * wake up on EAP identity request
         * wake up on 4-way handshake
         * wake up on rfkill release
         * wake up on network detection, up to 11 match sets
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports low priority scan.
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    P2P GO supports CT window setting
    P2P GO supports opportunistic powersave setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
    Device adds DS IE to probe requests
    Device can update TPC Report IE
    Device supports static SMPS
    Device supports dynamic SMPS
    Device supports WMM-AC admission (TSPECs)
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
    Device supports TDLS channel switching
```

Wifi card:

```
HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ lspci -vnn | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
```

```
HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ sudo iw reg get
global
country DE: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 13), (N/A)
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

phy#0 (self-managed)
country ID: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2437 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (2422 - 2462 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (2447 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (5735 - 5815 @ 20), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
```

```
HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE  SSID                MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY    
*       Cgates - Test WiFi  Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2        
        Cgates Free-5G      Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  --          
        --                  Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  97      ▂▄▆█  WPA2        
        Cgates - Test WiFi  Infra  48    270 Mbit/s  94      ▂▄▆█  WPA2        
        Cgates_A456         Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  90      ▂▄▆█  WPA2        
*       Cgates - Test WiFi  Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  WPA2        
        Cgates_A456_5G      Infra  120   270 Mbit/s  85      ▂▄▆█  WPA2        
        Cgates_D4E41F       Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  82      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2   
        --                  Infra  149   130 Mbit/s  82      ▂▄▆█  WPA2        
        DECO-M4_TEST        Infra  149   130 Mbit/s  82      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2   
        DECO-M4_TEST        Infra  4     270 Mbit/s  80      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2   
        Cgates Free-5G      Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  69      ▂▄▆_  --          
        --                  Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA2        
        4G-dDTv             Infra  3     270 Mbit/s  65      ▂▄▆_  WPA2        
        Cgates_D4E41F_5G    Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2   
        4G-dDTv-5G          Infra  52    405 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2        
        Cgates Free         Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  --          
        --                  Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  WPA2        
        --                  Infra  108   405 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2        
        Cgates Free-5G      Infra  108   405 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  --          
        Cgates Free-5G      Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  --          
        Glera EAP2 Guest    Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X 
        Glera Private 2GHz  Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA2        
        --                  Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA2        
        Cgates Free-5G      Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  --          
        IMCD-GUEST          Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA2        
        IMCD-USER           Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA2
```

Most 5 GHz bands are disabled. Any suggestions how I can enable them?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `sudo iw reg get` and also: `nmcli device wifi list` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

back same way like gone, after another update wifi 5GHz band works fine again:

```
HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ iw phy
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 20
    max scan IEs length: 422 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 20
    max # match sets: 11
    max # scan plans: 2
    max scan plan interval: 65535
    max scan plan iterations: 254
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Device supports T-DLS.
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x11ef
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
        HT Max RX data rate: 300 Mbps
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x11ef
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
        HT Max RX data rate: 300 Mbps
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        VHT Capabilities (0x038071b0):
            Max MPDU length: 3895
            Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
            RX LDPC
            short GI (80 MHz)
            TX STBC
            SU Beamformee
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5340 MHz [68] (disabled)
            * 5360 MHz [72] (disabled)
            * 5380 MHz [76] (disabled)
            * 5400 MHz [80] (disabled)
            * 5420 MHz [84] (disabled)
            * 5440 MHz [88] (disabled)
            * 5460 MHz [92] (disabled)
            * 5480 MHz [96] (disabled)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
            * 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
            * 5885 MHz [177] (disabled)
            * 5905 MHz [181] (disabled)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_config
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * frame
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * tdls_mgmt
         * tdls_oper
         * start_sched_scan
         * probe_client
         * set_noack_map
         * register_beacons
         * start_p2p_device
         * set_mcast_rate
         * connect
         * disconnect
         * channel_switch
         * set_qos_map
         * add_tx_ts
         * set_multicast_to_unicast
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    WoWLAN support:
         * wake up on disconnect
         * wake up on magic packet
         * wake up on pattern match, up to 20 patterns of 16-128 bytes,
           maximum packet offset 0 bytes
         * can do GTK rekeying
         * wake up on GTK rekey failure
         * wake up on EAP identity request
         * wake up on 4-way handshake
         * wake up on rfkill release
         * wake up on network detection, up to 11 match sets
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports low priority scan.
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    P2P GO supports CT window setting
    P2P GO supports opportunistic powersave setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
    Device adds DS IE to probe requests
    Device can update TPC Report IE
    Device supports static SMPS
    Device supports dynamic SMPS
    Device supports WMM-AC admission (TSPECs)
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
    Device supports TDLS channel switching
```

I thing it was something with Intel wifi microcode/firmware. I checked with my colleagues they have same problem with different HP Elite book models with different Intel wifi cards, now for everyone works just fine.